# How do I reference a CSS file on my ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I added the following to my page:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
```

And this is what the .CSS file looks like:

```
.form {
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

<body>
   <form runat="server" class="form">
..
....

</body>
```

However, when I go to see the page in IE, nothing is changing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the form in your css file? or is that just a typo?

Comment: Does this work in any other browsers?

Comment: yes, the CSS file class is called ".form". I'm trying it on a diff. browser now. hang on

Comment: it was a browser issue. this is strange. it didnt work on IE but it worked on Chrome.

Comment: IE is aggressive with caching. Clear the cache or do a hard reload (ctrl+F5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser issue. Cleared the cache for IE9 and did a control F5. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change it to `<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`.

Also, ensure that that the path to the stylesheet is correct.

Be sure you have a DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your file.

Comment: No luck. I added type="text/css" and double checked the path.

Comment: Did you check the capitalization is the same as well?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use "Url.Content" to make sure it looks in the right directory from root.

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```